# Google cloud platform exposing key

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I got this warning showing for several apps that is GCP api keys exposed. Please provide solutions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG0jj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to refer to [these guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key).

In summary:

- Make sure that your code doesn't include implicit hard-coded API keys directly before releasing it.
- Don't store API keys in files inside your application's source tree.
- Make sure to rotate the relevant API keys that are currently exposed to avoid any possible issues.